# Workaround to keep Android phone unlocked when connected to home WiFi

Tags: android, sleep, android-wake-lock

I am one of those people who do not like keeping location services on all the time.

Which puts me in a situation where I cannot keep my phone unlocked at home via Smart Lock by location.

I read quite a few posts on the subject on why smart lock is not applicable and will not be applicable officially to WiFi networks - mainly 'cuz of spoofing.

So I am trying to find a simple non-intrusive workaround for this to use on my phone at home.

I was thinking about a combination of the following two options here:
[Screen Lock Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFwq8.jpg)

**Automatically lock after sleep** - set to i.e. 5seconds
**Power button instantly locks** - turned off

So my idea is to achieve that with a simple background running app that would listen for sleep triggered by the power button.
After such sleep event is triggered the app will re-trigger sleep in 4s only if connected to my home WiFi network ( in other words reset that *5s automatically lock after sleep* timer).
This would keep my phone in a sleep but not-locked state.

Once I leave home/turn off my WiFi or wake up my phone the app will return in the listening state.

What I am not sure is.. is it possible to trigger sleep event manually?